# How do I prioritize which part of a page should load 1st?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

Okay guys I have a website that has a lights off for videos source code: http://www.megaptery.com/allofthelights/ 
An organic tabs for videos using Jquery 
and a 2buttons which onclick it changes the CSS of the whole page you know it's kinda like a theme for the page
Here is an example of one of my page:
http://myanimesekai.com/Watch/Noucome-Episode-9

okay all of them works perfectly fine on my laptop all of them IE, Mozilla and the OLD Google Chrome.
But Then I tried it on my Brothers Laptop BUT his Google Chrome is the latest Google Chrome the Google Chrome where the scrollbar changed. The problem is that the Lights off feature is malfunctioning it doesn't turn off the video only. But the Organic Tabs and The 2buttons works perfectly fine. So I tried it on an internet Cafe and this is where I was really frustrated their Google Chrome is also updated and then both 3 of them were malfunctioning then after a while I tried them on Mozilla and all of them worked perfectly fine and so I have an Idea maybe it's becaused it took time for the Jquery and my Javascript to load which is why all 3 of them were malfunctioning.
so my question is is there a way for me to make my page load the jquery and javascript 1st? or am I missing something that the new Google Chrome requires? this is really frustrating me

oh BTW the 2buttons that changes the CSS are the B and M squares Below the facebook page

Comment: Your question is very confusing, can you please try to elaborate more and please include version numbers of the browsers that don't work currently? For Chrome you can find version numbers under your menu->help

Comment: 33.0.1750.117 < Google chrome where the lights off doesn't work

Comment: 31.0.1650.63 < My Google Chrome version which works perfectly well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many errors on this page (http://myanimesekai.com/Watch/Noucome-Episode-9) that any one error can cause the page not to work.

You need to clean up your code quite a bit:

```
<script src="http://myanimesekai.com/javascript.js"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://myanimesekai.com/organictabs.jquery.js"></script>
```

You are calling jQuery in your javascript.js file. The jQuery library has not been declared before your scripts. You need to restructure your code to (you only need one version of jQuery):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://myanimesekai.com/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="http://myanimesekai.com/organictabs.jquery.js"></script>
```

This will fix some errors. I suggest that you look at the console for further errors and fix them.

Comment: When I changed it into that order it doesn't load my CSS

Comment: so I changed it into this order
    <script src="http://myanimesekai.com/javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://myanimesekai.com/organictabs.jquery.js"></script>

so I do only need 1 Jquery this helps a little so Thanks!